# element is always empty in IE 8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

I have the following code:

```
 if (document.querySelectorAll('[id$=":maindiv:usernametext::content"]')[0].value == null || document.querySelectorAll('[id$="maindiv:usernametext::content"]')[0].value.trim() == "") {
        console.log("maindiv:usernametext::content IS EMPTY !!!);
    }
```

Inside of IE 8, this element always says the value is empty even though it is not. When running inside of a browser > IE 8 as well as Chrome and Firefox it works. Why does it return null every-time. I am running in IE 8 standards mode.

**UPDATE**

So I just **`console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[id$=":maindiv:usernametext::content"]')[‌​0].value)`** and it is returning the value, but this condition is not working? So it seems the selector is grabbing the value, but this if statement is executing when it shouldn't since there is a value? This field is just a text field.

Comment: Are you sure `document.querySelectorAll('[id$=":maindiv:usernametext::content"]')` is returning any elements?

Comment: Protip: `QSA()[0]` === `querySelector();`

Comment: @RocketHazmat It is returning in all other browsers, except for IE 8

Comment: IE8 only has partial support for querySelector/querySelectorAll

Comment: @SterlingArcher Would my query be supported?

Comment: @user2924127 you're using `querySelectorAll()[0]` which grabs every element that matches the selector, and then return the first instance. `querySelector()` does returns the first instance of a selector match.

Comment: According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector), "Partial support in IE8 is due to being limited to CSS 2.1 selectors and a small subset of CSS 3 selectors (see notes there). Additionally, it will have trouble with selectors including unrecognized tags (for example HTML5 ones)."

Comment: @SterlingArcher I tried to change to querySelector previously, but it had no change. I don't believe I am using css3 at all?

Comment: From what I see, that's a CSS3 selector. So I don't think IE8 will support you here.

Comment: So I just console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[id$=":maindiv:usernametext::content"]')[0].value) and it is returning the value, but this condition is not working?

Comment: @Sterling Archer: It's one of the few CSS3 selectors that is fully supported by IE8 (keep in mind we're looking at a lone attribute selector here).

Comment: Suggest using `===` rather than `==`. (don't see why that would make a difference, but worth trying and probably a good idea anyway)

Comment: rewrite to make the code clearer: `var e=document.querySelector('[id$=":maindiv:usernametext::content"]'); if(e===null || e.value.trim() === '') { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out trim is not supported by IE 8 and I removed it and it works!

Comment: Click the green tick icon to should mark the answer as 'accepted'. That'll help anyone else who might be stuck on a similar problem to find the answer.

Comment: You have to wait two days to accept your own answer.